# Is it good practice to store google tokens in local storage

Tags: reactjs, api, security, websecurity

I am bit confused after reading few articles, basically assume you have a web app which uses gmail login for authentication. Is it a good practice to store the google access token in the local storage and send it via headers to verify in back end APIs ? or should I use separate mechanism to handle api level access ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not matter where will you save tokens at front-end, because even in a case when you will be exchanging them witch back-end - you will need to send them with the request.
(all data which is placed at front-end is unsecured)

So everyone will have access to them inside the inspector network tab.

When a question is going about security, the first rule:

- Research possibility to implement that at back-end by using environment variables.

P.S: I just opened [Authorizing Your App with Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth) and there are says:

Get started:
To get started, see **Implementing Server-side Authorization**.

So you need to handle all of the Authorization actions at back-end where all the tokes will be secured.